# Phantom Windows PowerShell profile on Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, powershell, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

When I start Windows PowerShell in Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit, it runs an (incorrect) profile -- but I cannot see that PowerShell code in any of my Windows PowerShell profile files. *[edit...]* So where could that errant profile be located? I sure can't see it with the tools I am using.

Comment: This isn't a question. The more effort you put into your question the better quality answers you'll tend to get.

Answer (score 3):

In 64-bit Windows, there are 2 sets of locations for system-wide PowerShell profiles:

```
%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\...
%windir%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\...
```

To view the 64-bit (i.e. native) version of the PowerShell profile files in a 32-bit application, you need to look at **%windir%\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell**. (In a 64-bit application, the 64-bit programs will be in the (now mis-named) **system32**.)

*(Yes, it is possible to create a bad PowerShell profile that you cannot see with 32-bit tools unless you use **sysnative** -- I did it earlier today by accident.)*